# Authenticatable Token Timeout

Tags: authentication, devise, oauth-2.0, warden

After issuing a token using the TokenAuthenticatable class in Devise, I want it to expire
after a predetermined amount of time.

Is there a way to set expiration time to an TokenAuthenticatable object in Devise?

Thanks